# ASP.NET MVC | HOW to update specific column through EF using Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, entity-framework

Im New to ASP.NET MVC.

im just learning MVC and i am stuck in a situation where i want to update data in database using Ajax and EF.

I am using code first approach.

I have two projects in my solution. First is The Web MVC project named as `Gem`, The other i have entities in it with project name `Gem.Domain`

I have this entity named `Category` with file name `Category.cs`

```
namespace Gem.Domain
{
    public class Category
    {
        public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength]
        public virtual string Description {get;set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

with datasource file

```
namespace Gem.Domain
{
    public interface IStoreDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
        IQueryable<Category> Categories { get; }
    }
}
```

Now in other Project Named `Web`

I have Area Registered with Name `Admin` which contains some controllers, but to be specific `CategoriesController.cs` reside in it.

And i have this method in this CategoriesController

```
public string UpdateCategoryName_DT(Category category)
{
    return "Just A Test";
}
```

Finally coming to view.

I want to use ajax on a popup that appears on datatables.

[image]

Ajax request works fine.. and request do generates to correct method.

Here is my ajax code.

```
    //Category Name Update Using Ajax.
    $('#datatable').on('click', '.editable-submit', function () {

        var rowID = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var updatedCategoryName = $(this).parents('div').siblings('div.editable-input').find('input').val();

        var postData = {
            ID: rowID,
            CategoryName: updatedCategoryName
        };

        //For Ajax Request.
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:JSON.stringify(postData),
            url:"@Url.Action("UpdateCategoryName_DT", "Categories", new { area = "Admin" })",
            success: function (output) {
                console.log(output);
            }
        });
});
```

Below is generated Ajax Request screen cap, using firebug for showing post info.

[image]

**Main Question:**

I want to know how to get the posted values in the controller through this ajax request and update the category name in database on base of posted values.
e-g i am getting ID of row and New Category name in ajax post, and i want to update the record in category table in database using entity framework.

How to do it, and what is the right method as i am  using ajax.

I have tried youtube and tutorials but i am not understanding it.

I have DBContext with name of `StoreDb` which resides in Gem Project and Infrastructure Folder.

```
namespace Gem.Infrastructure
{
    public class StoreDb : DbContext, IStoreDataSource
    {
        public StoreDb() : base("GemStoreConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        IQueryable<Product> IStoreDataSource.Products
        {
            get
            {
                return Products;
            }
        }

        IQueryable<Category> IStoreDataSource.Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return Categories;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

plus i am using structuremap.mvc5 dependency resolution.

```
namespace Gem.DependencyResolution {
    using Domain;
    using Infrastructure;
    using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
    using StructureMap.Graph;

    public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public DefaultRegistry() {
            Scan(
                scan => {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
                });
            For<IStoreDataSource>().Use<StoreDb>();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

i am new but i have did this setup using tutorial for what i have understood so far. but there is nothing related to ajax so i need little help with ajax.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Update:

Used a debugger, i think i am getting null, values are posting fine but i am getting null in controller ?

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-

**Update 2:**

i removed the `JSON.stringify()` and changed the Posted Data to this

```
var postData = {
                    CategoryID: rowID,
                    Name: updatedCategoryName
                };
```

As now it matches to schema, so its working now..

[image]

but on other hand it also exposes my DB Schema. What if i want to post Ajax with Different ValuesNames, other than the database column names, what to do in that case?

Comment: I think you question should be separated in two parts. One problem is how to read the category data in request and create instance of Category in c# and the second is how to save this to database. Am I correct?

Comment: @MartinBrabec No. i can read data perfectly. What i want is to update the data. i mean when i click on text, popup appears as you can see in picture. when i update text and press the tick button, ajax request generates.

but i want to know how to further work on it. how to update database using that ajax post

Comment: If you already have instance of C# object you want to save to the database using EF, then it is irrelevant how the object was created and the problem is how to save the object to database, am I right now?

Comment: @MartinBrabec
Yes, but im reading data for datatables in different method..
i have different method for view and this ajax request is posting to different method.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you are not much familiar with HTTP concept.

The simpliest way to read the object from ajax request (or any other POST request) is to update your Category model property names to match the once in json request (you can keep the first letter upper in c#, the rest has to be the same). Right now, your model has CategoryID and CategoryName, but in the json request, you are sending ID and Name parameters. Then, you need to add [FromBody] attribute to you action:

```
public string UpdateCategoryName_DT([FromBody]Category category)
{
    return "Just A Test";
}
```

The attribute tells the framework, that it should parse the json from body of the request and creates an instance of Category object. Then you will not get null in as seen in your updated question.

UPDATE

You can have different names in json request and in database. You just need to use JsonProperty attribute on the property.

```
public class Category
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "yourDesiredNameInJsonRequest")]
        public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public virtual int ParentCategory { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "yourAnotherDesiredNameInJsonRequest")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength]
        public virtual string Description {get;set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

To clarify the code above - the attribute will tell Json.Net to deserialize property "yourDesiredNameInJsonRequest" in your json and save it to Category.CategoryID field. It is just mapping.

Comment: Getting type or namespace error when i use [FromBody]?

Comment: You need to add `using System.Web.Http;` see [`FromBodyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: problem solved without the frombody but there is another issue please see update 2 in my question.